# Spring Data JPA/ Hibernate get one column value based on the id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Spring data JPA get the name based on the id

```
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

How to get the name only this the sql `SELECT name from Student where id = 2;`

I'm new in Spring data JPA, thanks in advance

Comment: Provide the repository that you have related to this entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById(ID) you can just call findById(Long id)

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
}

public YourClass(StudentRepo studentRepo) {
  Student student = studentRepo.findById(42L);
}
```

Credit to @Slevin for correcting my answer

Comment: That wasn't the question that was asked.   Read the docs.  getReferenceById replace getById

Comment: You are correct.  Thanks for correcting me and keeping things civil :P

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this code in **StudentRepository** ?

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select c.name from Student c where  id= :id")
    String getNameById(@Param("id") Long  id);

}
```